# CSS not working when I append a Elemts with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#add").click(function (e){
    count = count + 1;
    event.preventDefault()
    $("#products").append('<div class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-2"><select name="product'+count+'" type="text" class="input w-full border col-span-6">{% for product in products %}<option>{{product.name}}</option>{% endfor %}</select><input type="text" class="input w-full border col-span-3" placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity'+ count +'"><button class="input w-full border col-span-3 button w-24 inline-block border border-theme-6 text-theme-6" id="delete">-</button><br/></div>');
    document.getElementById('total_p').value=count;
});
```

> I have this jquery function to add another div to a list, however every time I called the function the element that is appended does not take the class style. 
>   Any suggestions?

Comment: It should take the class style. 1) Make sure that the CSS is loaded on your page.  2) Make absolutely sure that there are no typos whatsoever in the class name and/or CSS respectively.

Comment: Which exact styles are not applied? A lot of CSS is not applied to `option` elements at all, you also might have conflicting CSS rules. We really need a reproducible example to give you an answer.